# Please specify the product's option(s). in Magento 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am getting this error message after clicking the addtocart in configurable product and it redirects to same page for ex on: `example.com/shoes/ballet-flats/sample-product-for-size.htm‌​l` it will redirect to `example.com/sample-product-for-size.html` and it will showing the above

This is the addtocart button:

```
<a class="btn btn--wd text-uppercase add-to-cart-btn-19" title="Add to Cart" id="product-addtocart-button" onclick="setLocation('http://www.example.com/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy50ZXN0LmxpZmUyZ3Jvdy5jb20vbmV3bWFnZS9pbmRleC5waHAvc2hvZXMvYmFsbGV0LWZsYXRzL3NhbXBsZS1wcm9kdWN0LWZvci1zaXplLmh0bWw_X19fU0lEPVU,/product/19/form_key/nFMGNwWvjSyCQIMq/')">Add to Cart</a>
```

I am getting the above after clicking the addtocart in configurable product and it redirects to same page for ex:http://www.domain.com/shoes/ballet-flats/sample-product-for-size.html it will redirect to http://www.domain.com/sample-product-for-size.html and it will

This is the console error[image]

Comment: Can u elaborate more ? what are you asking

Comment: please give me url or provide us your browser console errors , your console must have some js error that is why you are seeing this issue

Comment: yes i am getting this error

Answer (score 0):

It could be an https issue. I had secure urls enabled in the frontend but when I inspected the page the form was trying to submit to the cart to http:// which chrome stops hence the page loads with an error as if you did not submit any product options.

I can't offer more information on why that is the case but one option which would resolve it would be to place https as your both your secure & unsecure urls to ensure all forms will include targets to https://.

System > Configuration > Unsecure

Answer (score 0):

I added this a seperate answer because it was a completely different solution/cause to the https answer but gives exactly the same route level outcome of "Please specify the product's option(s)".

Some of our url's were listed in our sitemap with ..., and commas (the product titles were not filtered correctly and the titles included things like eat, sleep, repeat)

As a result when I noticed this - I setup redirects to remove the ... to redirect to the correct page. As a result this broke certain add to cart links which contain ,
    https://www.fancyatshirt.co.uk/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuZmFuY3lhdHNoaXJ0LmNvLnVrL21lbnN0c2hpcnQtZWF0LXNsZWVwLXJ1Z2J5LXJlcGVhdA,,/product/128670/form_key/yxNNuz5Ce25w8jBi/

So it just reinforces you should be careful when writing redirects...